# ability and inabilty (Positive and negative)

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, prefixes

Context: I am not good at drawing, so which sentence should I use?

Don't judge me by my ability to draw

or

Don't judge me by my inability to draw

Comment: If you fear being criticised because you can't draw, use the second one.

Comment: I don't think many people would see any semantic difference at all in the ***ability / inability*** choice here. In nearly all contexts the meaning would be *I'm not very good at drawing, so please don't use that as the yardstick by which you measure my worth as a person*.  It would be a rather contrived context if the speaker *was* very good at drawing, but didn't want the addressee to assume that he was therefore good in other respects. And in that "unlikely" context, a sensible speaker would probably choose different phrasing to avoid people mistakenly applying the default interpretation.